# retrive sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysqli

SQL query to retrive the following condition. There are two cloumns one with user_id;s as primary keys and another tale as manager key. i want to retrive the query so that it displays manager key along with the user id's as manager 1, manager 2

Comment: can you give an example with actual data and expected output?

Comment: user_id manager_name
 2        abc
 46       def
 12       mfg
 
 output as
 abc 2
 def 46
 mfg 12

Answer (score 0):

Try this: you can achieve this using a self join

```
SELECT e1.name, e1.managerid, e2.name, e2.user_id
FROM Employee e1
INNER JOIN Employee e2
ON e1.managerid= e2.user_id
```

Comment: but 1 2 are the user id's. i want the user id's  to be attcahed along with the manager names

Comment: give your sample output

Comment: user_id  manager_name
1        kavya
45       naresh

output
kavya 1
naresh 45

Comment: try the with the change query

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can use the same approach for finding the heirarchy:

```
SELECT e1.name AS EmployeeName
    ,e1.user_id AS USERID
    ,e2.name AS ManagerName1
    ,e2.user_id AS ManagerID1
    ,e3.name AS ManagerName2
    ,e3.user_id AS ManagerID2
FROM Employee e1
LEFT JOIN Employee e2
    ON e1.managerid = e2.user_id
LEFT JOIN Employee e3
    ON e2.managerid = e3.user_id
```